# AWS Application Load Balancer unable to connect to Tableau Service Manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, tableau-api, amazon-elb

I'm trying to connect my application load balancer to the tableau service manager.
However, the status of the registered target is always unhealthy with the message

> Health checks failed with these codes: [502]

In the target group's registered target, I'm pointing to the instance using **instance_id** and to **port 8850** where the tableau service manager(TSM) is. The security group is currently set to allow all inbound and outbound for testing.

When accessing TSM using **https://<ip_address>:8850**, I can reach it without any issues but not when using the domain name **http://<domain_name>:8850**.

Did I miss out any additional configuration?

Comment: The `domain_name` your custom domain, or the one provided by ALB?

Comment: its my own custom domain from route 53

Comment: So you setup alias record to the ALB's dns name in R53?

Comment: Also why would HTTPS work when IP address is used, but you are using only HTTP for the domain. Did you set HTTP listener, or only HTTPS listener for ALB?

Comment: yup, from route 53 pointing to ALB's dns name. I have 2 listeners for the ALB. One for HTTPS (443) and the other for HTTP (8850)

Comment: So this `https://<ip_address>:8850` is for accessing instance directly, without ALB? If so, have you setup HTTPS for target group?

Comment: omg, thanks for pointing out my mistake there! The target is healthy now. Appreciate your help man!

Comment: Glad to hear. If you don't mind I will make an answer for future reference.

Comment: yes, go ahead. i will accept your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was that **target group** (TG) was not set for **HTTPS**.

The solution was to **fix the TG settings** so that it can work with HTTPS that is used on the instances.